# multiple pivot on same column in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

How can I have pivot define on same column in tsql?

for example:

```
 SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT CAST(start_time AS DATE) AS [Date],
 DATEPART(hour,start_time) AS [Hour], 
 Count(is_sale)AS  [Sales Count] 
 ,Count(is_not_sale)AS  [No Sales Count] 
 FROM  prov_sales WITH(NOLOCK)
 GROUP BY CAST(start_time AS DATE), DATEPART(hour,start_time)) AS HourlySalesData

 PIVOT( SUM([Sales Count]) FOR [Hour] IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7],
     [8], [9], [10],[11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], 
     [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23])) AS DatePivot1

 PIVOT( SUM([No Sales Count]) FOR [Hour] IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7],
     [8], [9], [10],[11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], 
     [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23])) AS DatePivot2
```

My above tsql is not working as I am getting error for the hour column which has repeated values from [1] to [23].

Comment: Without sample data and expected results we can't only guess here, but one reason I prefer using a Cross Tab instead of the `PIVOT` operator is because you don't need to use `PIVOT` more than once for multiple pivots. Also, on a different note, why `WITH(NOLOCK)`? I *assume* you understand the implications of using it, correct?

Comment: Thank you let me explore Cross tab.

Answer (score 1):

As PIVOT creates Column names from the IN list, you cannot define same column like [1] twice. Although the following solution is not a standard one, but it may server your purpose-

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT CAST(start_time AS DATE) AS [Date],
--Created the hour column twice for Pivoting twice
'Sales_' + CAST(DATEPART(hour,start_time) AS VARCHAR) AS [Hour_Sales], 
'NoSales_' + CAST(DATEPART(hour,start_time) AS VARCHAR) AS [Hour_NoSales], 
Count(is_sale)AS  [Sales Count] 
,Count(is_not_sale)AS  [No Sales Count] 
FROM  prov_sales WITH(NOLOCK)
GROUP BY CAST(start_time AS DATE), DATEPART(hour,start_time)) AS HourlySalesData

PIVOT( SUM([Sales Count]) FOR [Hour_Sales] IN ([Sales_0], [Sales_1], [Sales_2], [Sales_3], [Sales_4], [Sales_5], [Sales_6], [Sales_7],
     [Sales_8], [Sales_9], [Sales_10],[Sales_11], [Sales_12], [Sales_13], [Sales_14], [Sales_15], [Sales_16], 
     [Sales_17], [Sales_18], [Sales_19], [Sales_20], [Sales_21], [Sales_22], [Sales_23])) AS DatePivot1

PIVOT( SUM([No Sales Count]) FOR [Hour_NoSales] IN ([NoSales_0], [NoSales_1], [NoSales_2], [NoSales_3], [NoSales_4], [NoSales_5], [NoSales_6], [NoSales_7],
     [NoSales_8], [NoSales_9], [NoSales_10],[NoSales_11], [NoSales_12], [NoSales_13], [NoSales_14], [NoSales_15], [NoSales_16], 
     [NoSales_17], [NoSales_18], [NoSales_19], [NoSales_20], [NoSales_21], [NoSales_22], [NoSales_23])) AS DatePivot2
```

Comment: My all columns are same from [1]-[23] for each row of sales and nosales

Comment: That's why I have added prefix Sales_ & NoSales_ to them to get expected output. Of course the column names will be different than your expectation.